# Implementing Sort/Filter/Pagination operations using OData with collections of complex type, returned by store procedure

Tags: c#, wpf, odata

I have an n-tier application. Client and application server interact with the OData protocol. I can implement Sort/Filter/Pagination only with database entities, provided by Entity Framework. 
C#

```
DataServiceQuery<MyEntity> CAQuery = WebService.MyEntity;
CA = new QueryableDataServiceCollectionView<WagonReestr>(WebService, CAQuery);
CA.PageSize = 10;
CA.MoveToFirstPage();
CA.Load(true);
```

XAML

```
<t:RadGridView Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CA}" 
                     IsBusy="{Binding Path=CA.IsBusy}" 
                     ShowGroupPanel="False" AutoGenerateColumns="True"/>
<t:RadDataPager Grid.Row="3" Source="{Binding Path=CA}"/>
```

DataServiceQuery provides OData queries such hxxp://...service.svc/MyEntity?$skip=20&$top=10
My service provides an OData API based on ObjectContext, generated from my database.

I need to provide the same ability to the stored procedure result, which will return a list of complex type. May be there is some way to implement my own entity in the ObjectContext and work with it with a stored procedures without mapping to database entity? Or may be other solution?

Can anyone share the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar need in our project, and we ended up defining a fake entity in our model that didn't not have a corresponding table in the physical database. We used this entity type to return data from the stored procedure.

Here's roughly what we did. Our stored procedure returned a collection of a type DistributionFiles that could be defined as a complex type. Instead we defined it as an entity type. It resulted in the following model changes:

1. Storage model:

   ```
   <EntityType Name="DISTRIBUTION_FILES">
     <Key>
           ... keys
     </Key>
       ... properties
   </EntityType>
   ```
2. Conceptual model:

   <EntitySet Name="DistributionFiles" EntityType="Model.DistributionFiles" />
3. Function definition:

   <FunctionImport Name="GetDistributionFiles" 
   EntitySet="DistributionFiles" ReturnType="Collection(Model.DistributionFiles)">
4. Mapping:

   ```
   <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="Model.DistributionFiles">
     <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="DISTRIBUTION_FILES">
       ... field mapping
     </MappingFragment>
   </EntityTypeMapping>
   ```

Then I could use DistributionFiles entity as there was a corresponding table. There only place it was really used was a stored procedure GetDistributionFiles that returned a collection of this entities.